# Regex replace for quotes and double quotes in react native doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, react-native

How to allow the double quotes (") and single quote (') in react native

I was unable allow those, when i try in the web it's work for me but when i try it into react native in ios simulator the single quotes and double quotes are always replace

here is the code

`const regexReplace = value.replace(/[^\w\s_.,-/#-'"]/g, '');`

is there is something in react native made single quotes and double quotes are not escape from the regex validation

Comment: Try `/[^\w\s.,-/#-&]/g`. I removed `'` and `"` and changed the `#-'` range to `#-&` since `&` is `\x26` and `'` is `\x27`. Note `\w` matches `_`, so I removed `_` as well.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it still not working, however the single quotes are double quotes are still replaced

Comment: Ok, try `/[^\w\s.,-/#-'"‘’“”]/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to support both *straight* and *curly* quotes.

Thus, you can use

```
/[^\w\s.,-/#-'"‘’“”]/g
```

See the `‘`, `’`, `“` and `”` added to the character class.